# Dereferencing a void pointer who points to another pointer

Tags: c, pointers

I'm attempting to understand C depplier and in one of my nirvanenses meditations got this question "how to dereferencing a void pointer that points to another kind of pointer", I guess it could get clearer with the next code:

```
int a,b,*p1,*p2;
void *p;
a=3;
b=6
p1=&a;
p2=&b
p=&p1;
*p=p2 //How I could be able to do this?
```

So in the above code I want that p1 points at the same value that points p2 using as an intermediate p. I know it could be better just doing p1=p2 but I want to know if what I wrote above it's possible

Comment: You can answer your own question if you determine how you would do it in machine code aka assembly. C is just a slightly higher level, more portable assembly.

Comment: Also, a void pointer has no use in itself. It must be cast or assigned to another pointer type first. Void pointers exist only for holding pointers of unknown type. For use by callback functions or event messages for example.

Comment: void pointers cannot be dereferenced... you need to cast it first, otherwise the compiler doesn't know what the size of the target is.

Comment: so @vanza, Do you know how can I cast it in this case?, I mean because p1 is pointing to another pointer

Comment: @ZanLynx I don't know much about assembler, I'm gonna look for it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`void *` pointers *must not* be dereferenced.  They are only ever useful as an intermediate pointer storage if you do not want to dereference it.  (Think of `malloc`.)

Before you dereference a `void *` pointer, you must cast it to a non-`void` type so

```
*((int * *) p) = p2;
```

would have worked in your example.  Of course, you must be sure that the cast is meaningful or arbitrary bad things may happen.  The compiler won't be able to assist you here.

Comment: Hey thanks, I just got a question, it's necessary that dereference of p2, I mean because I want the adress that p2 appoints?

Comment: @KevinMejia Not only is it not necessary, it's plain wrong.  Sorry, this was a typo.  I will correct my answer.